# Error 80070570 when installing Vista

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista

First some background:

I'm trying to upgrade the hard drive in an Advent 5301 laptop. I've already tried cloning it, but I couldn't get that method to work. So now I'm trying to install Vista onto the new hard drive using an OEM installation disc.

For some reason, there's no settings in the BIOS. I think they've been locked off by the OEM. I therefore cannot view or change IDE/AHCI settings, CPU voltages, etc. Pretty much all I can do is change the boot order.

Now the problem:

When I run the Vista installation, everything seems to progress as it should. I have formatted and partitioned the hard drive successfully, so there should effectively be no data there to interfere with the installation. Since the laptop recognises the hard drive and partitions, I'm assuming this means that Vista's drivers are compatible with the new hard drive?

The error appears after copying the files to the hard drive. "Extracting files" completes, then after some time "Copying files" gets to 100% but then raises this message:

> Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation.

I've checked the disc; it's in immaculate condition, and has always been stored in its case.

I'd like to know if there's any other steps I can take to get Vista onto this new hard drive. Any help is much appreciated!

---

EDIT:

I've now tried downloading the installation disc from the internet, creating a bootable drive and booting it that way. No luck; I was presented with the same error message at the same stage in the installation. This rules out problems with the installation media and the using the laptop's disc drive.

I've tried using different RAM in the laptop. Again, the error message reared its ugly head. This rules out problems with the memory.

Could this issue be a limitation applied by the manufacturer, whereby only a specific model of hard drive can be used? Even a specific serial number, paired when they assembled the laptop? This is not something I know much about.

Comment: A quick search says, it could be many reasons sadly. This includes faulty memory and faulty hard drive. Try slaving the hard drive in another computer and running a smart tool, and try using different RAM (or just 1 Chip). However, I suspect it's nature's way of helping you to avoid Vista...

Comment: Please update your question to include specifics about how you attempted to clone the HDD.  Vista supported IDE/AHCI out of the box unlike Windows XP which was more difficult and required you to supply the driver to add that support.  At the end of the day there are only two explainations really.  The first the disk actually is bad, easy enough to confirm, locate a different installation disk.  The second is the HDD, easy enough to confirm, try another HDD.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally due to the source being corrupted now as you say its fine condition so maybe the DVD drive itself. I would guess if it was the new drive you would have a different error.

It can be other hardware related such as memory (being the main one).

My advise is to use another machine (if possible) and create a bootable USB of the DVD using Microsoft's own tool:

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

You may need to create an ISO of the DVD first, quite a few free tools for this Magic ISO springs to mind unsure if its still free though!

Comment: While this is good advice.  I have problems using the same installation disk as the source for the ISO if we suspect the source data ( for the installation of Windows ) is corrupt.

Comment: I created an ISO of the disc, and was able to make a bootable USB using another machine. However, I got an error at the same point in the installation - though it was error code 0x80070003.
I might try to find some alternative RAM to see if that's the real cause of the problem.

Comment: Ah thats annoying sorry for the time wasting... If seeking RAM is going to be a nightmare then you can use that USB to run memtest see this link http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=409152 that will bring any RAM issues to light...